# LAST_INSERT_ID does not work

Tags: php, mysql

I have two submit buttons that get values from two forms and insert them in a database. The problem is that I need to get the last inserted id from the first table (courses) to insert into the second table (students) but it does not work. This what I did:

```php
<?php
$course_name = // the value of the field for the course name
$student_name = // The first name of the student
$student_age = // The age of the student
$last_id = // The last id of table courses
  if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
          $query1 = "INSERT INTO courses (course_name)VALUES ('$course_name')";
                if ($object->query($query1) === true){
                    $last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
                    $good = "the course has been created";
                }
                else{
                    $bad = "Error: " .$query1.$object->error;
                }
    }

 if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
          $query2 = "INSERT INTO students (course_id,student_name, student_age)VALUES ('last_id','$student_name','student_age')";
                if ($object->query($query2) === true){

                    $good = "the student has been created";
                }
                else{
                    $bad = "Error: " .$query2.$object->error;
                }
    }
?>
```

I do not know why it does not work.

Comment: For one thing, you left out `$` signs in 2 of these `'last_id','$student_name','student_age'` in your VALUES. If that's your actual code, it most likely is the reason why your code is failing. Those should read as `'$last_id','$student_name','$student_age'`. So, make those changes and then come back and tell us what the problem is; you never made a mention of what wasn't working.

Comment: We also don't know whether or not your variables and/or POST arrays have values or not and if they are correct. I for one won't be sticking around the question for hours on end, so you'll need to ping me directly.

Comment: I see you have a (bad) habit of not responding to comments left under your questions. I have given up on this one, so ask the person who left you an answer below, I will pass on this one. Good luck.

Comment: I am really sorry for that Fred-ii- thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned if you are using PDO or mysqli etc etc. If it's mysqli it  [$mysqli->insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php);

```
if ($object->query($query1) === true){
      $last_id = $object->insert_id
      $good = "the course has been created";
}
```

OTH, if you are using PDO it's [lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

```
if ($object->query($query1) === true){
      $last_id = $object->lastInsertId()
      $good = "the course has been created";
}
```

Comment: It is mysqli I am using. I do not know the reason why it still does not work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: please never use the words does not work. Always give the full error

Comment: Good morning! that is the problem it does not even display any error at all.

Comment: that is because you have not enabled error logging.